# Are discussions about a particular community allowed within the individual community?

Tags: discussion

For example - if I wanted to ask questions about the Physics community, should I ask them in the Physics community or not? Where else could I ask them?

Comment: Can you give us an example question?

Comment: Probably on [Physics Meta](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Meta-Questions like "how can we attract more users to the site?" or "what are things we can do to prevent the site from being deleted?" They don't belong here since they do rely on a lot of knowledge that's specific to the community (especially with the astronomy one, which is at risk of deletion in 40 days)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it is a question about Physics for example **ask** it in the [the community](https://physics.stackexchange.com/).

If it is a question **about the community** ask it on the [meta site](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Okay I see - thanks! I'll accept this answer when I'm allowed to

Answer (score 2):

> if I wanted to ask questions about the Physics community, should I ask them in the Physics community or not? Where else could I ask them?
>
> Meta-Questions like "how can we attract more users to the site?" or "what are things we can do to prevent the site from being deleted?

Such questions are best suited for Meta site of the particular community.